# How to specify an optional Date property in spring cloud contract?

Tags: spring-cloud, spring-cloud-contract

I'm trying to use spring cloud contract. I write a JSON body specification and I need a Date property to be optional. 
When I specify in groovy dsl:

```
"processingDate": $(consumer(optional(anyDate())), producer(anyDate())),
```

it fails:

```
Exception in thread "main" Assertion failed: 

assert testSide ==~ Pattern.compile(stubSide.optionalPattern())
       |        |           |       |        |
       |        false       |       |        (org.springframework.cloud.contract.spec.internal.ClientDslProperty(DslProperty(clientValue:(\d\d\d\d)-(0[1-9]|1[012])-(0[1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01]), serverValue:2016-06-16)))?
       |                    |       (org.springframework.cloud.contract.spec.internal.ClientDslProperty(DslProperty(clientValue:(\d\d\d\d)-(0[1-9]|1[012])-(0[1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01]), serverValue:2016-06-16)))?
       |                    (org.springframework.cloud.contract.spec.internal.ClientDslProperty(DslProperty(clientValue:(\d\d\d\d)-(0[1-9]|1[012])-(0[1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01]), serverValue:2016-06-16)))?
       org.springframework.cloud.contract.spec.internal.ClientDslProperty(DslProperty(clientValue:(\d\d\d\d)-(0[1-9]|1[012])-(0[1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01]), serverValue:2011-01-11))
```

It however works when using optional together with regex:

```
"processingDate": $(consumer(optional(regex(isoDate()))), producer(LocalDateTime.now().format(DateTimeFormatter.ISO_DATE))),
```

but obviously I do not want to use such a workaround for each optional field.

Thank you!

Comment: can you share your `groovy` contract file here?

Comment: The first code sample above is the related row from my groovy contract.

Answer (score 1):

`anyDate()` should be used directly like this:

```
"processingDate": ${anyDate()}
```

if you need a regular expression use `isoDate()`. It's a difference between using the delegates of `org.springframework.cloud.contract.spec.internal.PatternValueDslProperty` and `org.springframework.cloud.contract.spec.internal.RegexPatterns`

Answer (score 0):

Seems adding `regex` prefix in `consumer` side will do. Just try out changing

`"processingDate": $(consumer(optional(anyDate())), producer(anyDate())),` to

`"processingDate": $(consumer(optional(regex(anyDate()))), producer(anyDate())),`

OR

to `"processingDate": $(consumer(optional(regex(isoDate()))), producer('2016-06-16')),`

for details check-out [spring-cloud-contract_optional_parameters](https://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-static/spring-cloud-contract/1.0.0.RELEASE/#_passing_optional_parameters)